# Xcode fails during build

Tags: flutter, xcode, android-studio, apple-developer, apple-developer-account

First time app developer, and really really struggling on the very last step - building the app and sending to the App Store. Built the app in Flutter, using Android Studio. Have been using Xcode to run it on iOS simulator for a while now. But for some reason Xcode won't let me actually build the damn thing! Attached is the Xcode screen where I get two errors:

Communication with Apple failed

No profiles for *bundleid

Triple checked that the Bundle ID is correct. Also attached a screenshot of the user account in Xcode, confirming I'm an admin? A couple google searches on my end and I'm still unsure how to proceed. I'm assuming I missed something very basic and simple! I've worked so hard coding this app, and am super proud of it ... so it's incredibly deflating not being able to get it across the finish line.

Thank you for any help you could give me! Sorry if there's any information not included that I just don't know about.

[image: account info]

[image: errors]

Comment: Well.., try building it on a real iPhone or iOS emulator. And let me know the results

Comment: haven't tried it on a real device, but iOS simulator works seamlessly.

Comment: If you've succeeded on iOS simulator, the build will be successful on the actual iPhone. iOS build was successful, what in the world is the problem? What do you want?

If you look at the image above, the name you chose for the build target is Any iOS Device, of course, there will be an error.because Xcode don't have a device to build..

Comment: Sorry if my initial post wasn't clear! I'm trying to deploy the app to the App Store. My understanding is I have to set the device to any, then Product > Archive?

Comment: I see. You don't need to specify a device when you build it as an archive. Oh... archive failed, sorry

Comment: Any ideas on the error messages themselves? Seems like it's an issue with Xcode not communicating with my Apple Developer ID, and therefore not being able to match up certificates and/or bundleIDs? That's my very un-educated guess, at least.

Comment: I couldn't answer because there were so many suspicious parts and there were so many things to check. I think it's hard to guess the cause based on the information you just gave me. It's hard to write down all those doubts. You'd better list first what you've tried to solve this problem.

Comment: But if it's me, I'll see if the actual iPhone build, not the simulator, will succeed. If both are successful or only the simulator is successful, the cause is different.

Comment: I figured it out! Looks like it requires a physical device to be associated with the account, even if the intended goal is to publish directly to the App Store. Thanks for you help!